# Angular 9 + Firebase. Update property in database

Tags: javascript, angular, database, firebase

I'm working on a form for editing users phone number and city. I have input for phoneNumber and dropdown with cities.

**code in my change-contacts.component.ts :**

```
import { ActiveUserService } from 'src/app/services/active-user.service';
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UsersDbService } from 'src/shared/firebase/usersDb.service';
import { UserpanelUsersService } from 'src/pages/userpanel/userpanel-user.service';
import { LocalDataAndLogicService } from 'src/pages/userpanel/services/localDataAndLogic.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-change-contacts',
    templateUrl: './change-contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./change-contacts.component.scss'],
    //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class ChangeContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contactChangeForm: FormGroup

  constructor(
    public userpanelUsersService: UserpanelUsersService,
    public localDataAndLogicService: LocalDataAndLogicService,
    public usersDbService: UsersDbService,
    public activeUserService: ActiveUserService
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactChangeForm = new FormGroup({
        phoneNumber: new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.minLength(12),
            Validators.required
        ]),
        country: new FormControl(''),
        city: new FormControl('{{userpanelUsersService.user.sity}}')
    });
        console.log(this.userpanelUsersService.user.phoneNumber);
  }

  submitChange() {
      const formData = {...this.contactChangeForm.value};
    this.usersDbService.updateUsersProperty(this.userpanelUsersService.user.id, this.userpanelUsersService.user.sity, formData.city)
      this.usersDbService.updateUsersProperty(users, this.userpanelUsersService.user.phoneNumber, formData.phoneNumber)

  }
 }
```

**also I had 2 complited services:** 
1) *usersDbService*

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { FireBaseService } from './firebase.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersDbService {
  public collectionName: string = 'users';
  constructor(public db: FireBaseService, public auth: AuthService) {}
  public usersCollection (): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.getCollection(this.collectionName);
  }
  public usersItem(id: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.getItem(this.collectionName, id);
  }
  public deleteUser(id: any): void {
    this.db.deleteItem(this.collectionName, id);
  }
  public updateUser(item: any): void {
    this.db.updateItem(this.collectionName,item.id)
  }
  public addUser(item: any, id:any): void {
    this.db.addItem(this.collectionName,item,id);
  }
  public updateUsersProperty(id: any, name, value): void {
    this.db.updateItemsProperty(this.collectionName, id, name, value);
  }
  public addUserWithPasswordAndEmail(email:string,password:string): void {
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
  }
  public checkUserWithPasswordAndEmail(email:string,password:string): void {
    this.auth.signUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
  }
}
```

*and 2) userpanel-user.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IUser } from 'src/models/Users.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserpanelUsersService {
  public images: string[] = [];
  user: IUser | any = {
    id: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    fullName: '',
    phoneNumber: 1212122,
    email: '',
    gender: '',
    sity: '',
    country: '',
    rating: [],
    allowedWantsCardsNumber: 0,
    comments: [],
    images: this.images,
    successfulExchanges: 0
  };

  clear(): void {
    this.user = {
      id: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      fullName: '',
      phoneNumber: 1212122,
      email: '',
      gender: '',
      sity: '',
      country: '',
      rating: [],
      allowedWantsCardsNumber: 0,
      comments: [],
      images: [],
      successfulExchanges: 0
    };
  }
}
```

When I use this code from my component.ts there are no update property sity in my user collection but create new property named `oldCityName: newCityName` but I need `sity: newCityName.` Maybe I use wrong name property in updateUsersProperty.

What should I do?

Comment: from what I can see is you are using the value from this.userpanelUsersService.user.sity as the property name, this would be incorrect as you need to give the property name instead of the value

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how can I take property name with this methods?

Comment: well the easiest way, seeing you updating one property value at a time and its not dynamic, is to just type it out
`this.usersDbService.updateUsersProperty(this.userpanelUsersService.user.id, 'sity', formData.city)`

Comment: Not working with just string - ERROR FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field sity)